# How can I make my custom control fully clickable at designtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I created a custom control derived from `TScrollingWinControl` and from its constructor I create a new instance of another custom class derived from `TGraphicControl`.

The controls works perfectly fine except at designtime. If I use the mouse to click on the scrollbox portion of the control, then the Delphi designer shows the grab handle for the control and from there it can be moved and resized etc. However, if I click on the control where my `TGraphicControl` is then the parent control (the `TScrollingWinControl`) does not show the grab handles and cannot be moved or resized.

So my question is, how do I tell my custom control that by clicking on the `TGraphicControl` inside my parent, should be allowed to be moved and resized at designtime?

I tried looking at the ControlStyle flags such as `csDesignInteractive` and rebuilding the package and testing at designtime but it seemed to make no difference.

I also tried setting my `TGraphicControl` to `Enabled := False` and again rebuilding the package and testing at designtime, the difference here though is that the `TGraphicControl` can now be selected at designtime like any standard control, only it now has its own grab handles instead of the parent (`TScrollingWinControl`).

What do I need to do so that when clicking on the `TGraphicControl` the parent control (`TScrollingWinControl`) shows the grab handles and can be moved and resized?

Comment: Just as I asked the question I figured the answer - I was passing `nil` instead of `Self` when creating the `TGraphicControl` from the constructor and now it is fully functional at designtime.

Comment: You can post an answer to your question below.

Comment: @JerryDodge I have answered it now. It was one of those moments where I was scratching my head for ages trying to work out what I needed to do, then just as I asked the question I changed a simple thing like the owner and it worked, Oh well :)

Comment: B.t.w., your error seems like a great solution for preventing those grips!

Comment: @NGLN That's one way of looking at it I guess, I found this behavior/error by chance more than anything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as I asked the question I realised the answer.

From the constructor where I was creating my `TGraphicControl` I was passing `nil` for the owner. I have now changed it to `Self` and the control behaves correctly now in that selecting any part of my control at designtime shows the grab handles for the parent `TScrollingWinControl`.